# Battery replacement on MacBook Pro 13" Early 2011 considerations

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

I need to replace battery on MacBook Pro 13" Early 2011 and I've already found the one in the local shop, but I am not sure it will fit.

Old non-working battery has the following parameters:

**Model No:** A1322

**Part number:** 020-6764-A

**Type:** Li-ion Polymer

**Voltage:** 10.95V

**Power:** 63.5Wh

The one I found has the the same Model No, Type, Voltage with **Capacity 5800 mAh**, which is the same if converting Wh to mAh.

Should I pay attention to Part Number?

On site it is said the new battery is compatible with the following Part Numbers:

020-6547-A, 661-5229, 661-5557, A1322, MB990LL/A, MB991LL/A

and with the following models:

Apple MacBook Pro: MB990LLA 13-inch, MB991LLA 13-inch, MC024/A 17-inch, MC024CH/A 17-inch, MC024J/A 17-inch, MC024LL/A 17-inch, MC024TA/A 17-inch, MC024X/A 17-inch, MC024ZP/A 17-inch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This A1322 model battery fits many MBP 13's, all the way back to 2009 version. Given the number of iterations and countries MBP have been sold, it's due to have different part numbers.

I also have a MBP 13' Early 2011 version. Two months ago I replaced the battery with a A1322 battery I bought online and I haven't had a problem.

Beware that:

1. If you are going to ifixit yourself, taking out the battery requires a special screwdriver. I got mine as a free addon from the vender.
2. Download CoconutBattery. It's a free app that gives you information like manufacture date (which I cannot find under System Information) and charge cycles.

Comment: Yes, looks like A1322 model No. fits MacBook Pro 13" 2009-2012. Thx!